# не работает svg анимация при запуске сайта

Tags: html, svg, анимация

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1440 1024" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:anim="http://www.w3.org/2000/anim" anim="" anim:transform-origin="50% 50%" anim:duration="0.5" anim:ease="power1.inOut">
  <g id="5b536866e244db4cf7fcbccd5a5c86b8">
    <rect width="1440" height="1024" fill="white"></rect>
    <path id="02eaa2934adcabdcd2d34d09d9bddd8c" d="M720 480L747.713 528H692.287L720 480Z" fill="black"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

в самом svg прописана анимация, но при запуске отображается только статичная картинка

Comment: Какая вам нужна анимация? Вращение треугольника или что-то другое?

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю в каком фреймворке вы пытались сделать анимацию.
Также можно понять, что вы пытаетесь вращать весь SVG, а это плохая практика. Учитывая, что у вас треугольник находится сверху прямоугольника с неравными сторонами, то при вращении будет ломаться вёрстка.

Лучше вращать отдельно треугольник  внутри SVG.

Откройте сниппет:  ***`На всю страницу`***
*Запуск анимации после клика*

```html
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 1440 1024"  width="1440" height="1024" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <g id="5b536866e244db4cf7fcbccd5a5c86b8">
    <rect width="1440" height="1024" fill="white"></rect>
    <path id="02eaa2934adcabdcd2d34d09d9bddd8c" d="M720 480L747.713 528H692.287L720 480Z" fill="black">
       <animateTransform   attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" dur="1s" values="0 720 512;360 720 512" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Тимофей Если ответ вам был полезен, не забудьте отметить его, как решение. Галочка ниже цифры ответа